# Sublime TypeScript Build system error - env: node: No such file or directory (MacOS)

Tags: typescript, sublimetext3, ts-node

I'm trying to set up a TypeScript build system in Sublime Text with this config:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/Users/userName/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/bin/ts-node","$file"],
    "selector": "source.ts"
}
```

and i'm getting error like that:

```
env: node: No such file or directory
[Finished in 9ms with exit code 127]
[cmd: ['/Users/alex/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/bin/ts-node', '/Users/alex/Desktop/temp.ts']]
[dir: /Users/alex/Desktop]
[path: /opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

The wiredest thing is that when i setted up JS build system with almost identical config, it worked without any problems:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/Users/userName/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/bin/node", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.js"
}
```

Just in case, here's the output of `which ts-node`: `/Users/userName/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/bin/ts-node`

If i try to manually run comand `/Users/userName/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/bin/ts-node /Users/userName/Desktop/temp.ts` in terminal it also works.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Add `"/Users/userName/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/bin"` to your `PATH` variable in your `~/.profile` file. You may need to either log out and back in, or restart entirely for it to be applied.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, just logging in and out worked!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I needed just to log out and back in